# Complex XML parsing in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, xml-parsing

I have to read and display multiple character dialogues inside my book app. I am planning to store character dialogue data inside XML in following format:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Pages>
    <Page Id="P1">
        <T>Once upon a time in the deep jungle of sunderbun there lived a lazy and wicked Jackal.Once upon a time in the deep jungle of sunderbun there lived a lazy and wicked Jackal.</T>
        <A>This is audio file location.This is audio file location.This is audio file location.</A>
        <Dlg>
            <Dlg Id="C1D1" P="L" X="" Y="" W="" H="">
                <T>This is Character 1 Dialogue 1.This is Character 1 Dialogue 1.</T>
                <A>This is audio file location.This is audio file location.</A>
            </Dlg>
            <Dlg Id="C1D2" P="R" X="" Y="" W="" H="">
                <T>This is Character 1 Dialogue 2.This is Character 1 Dialogue 2.</T>
                <A>This is audio file location.This is audio file location.</A>
            </Dlg>
            <Dlg Id="C2D1" P="L" X="" Y="" W="" H="">
                <T>This is Character 2 Dialogue 1.This is Character 2 Dialogue 1.</T>
                <A>This is audio file location.This is audio file location.</A>
            </Dlg>
        </Dlg>
    </Page>
    <Page Id="P2">
        <T>Once upon a time in the deep jungle of sunderbun there lived a lazy and wicked Jackal.Once upon a time in the deep jungle of sunderbun there lived a lazy and wicked Jackal.</T>
        <A>This is audio file location.This is audio file location.This is audio file location.</A>
        <Dlg>
            <Dlg Id="C1D1" P="R" X="" Y="" W="" H="">
                <T>This is Character 1 Dialogue 1.This is Character 1 Dialogue 1.</T>
                <A>This is audio file location.This is audio file location.</A>
            </Dlg>
            <Dlg Id="C2D1" P="L" X="" Y="" W="" H="">
                <T>This is Character 2 Dialogue 1.This is Character 2 Dialogue 1.</T>
                <A>This is audio file location.This is audio file location.</A>
            </Dlg>
            <Dlg Id="C2D2" P="R" X="" Y="" W="" H="">
                <T>This is Character 2 Dialogue 2.This is Character 2 Dialogue 2.</T>
                <A>This is audio file location.This is audio file location.</A>
            </Dlg>
        </Dlg>
    </Page>
</Pages>
```

As you can see from the XML structure, there would be multiple pages and every page would have multiple characters and each character would have multiple dialogues. Size of this XML might be around 250 KB (not sure if that's too big for iPhone/iPad). I am planning to use GDataXML to parse this XML and store as following model object:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef enum {
    Left,
    Right
} DialoguePosition;

@interface Dialogue : NSObject{
    NSString *_id;
    int _frameX;
    int _frameY;
    int _frameWidth;
    int _frameHeight;
    DialoguePosition _dialoguePosition;
    NSString *_dialogueText;
    NSString *_dialogueAudioLocation;
}
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *id;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int frameX;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int frameY;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int frameWidth;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int frameHeight;
@property (nonatomic, assign) DialoguePosition dialoguePosition;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *dialogueText;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *dialogueAudioLocation;

- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)id frameX:(int)frameX frameY:(int)frameY frameWidth:(int)frameWidth frameHeight:(int)frameHeight dialoguePosition:(DialoguePosition)dialoguePosition dialogueText:(NSString *)dialogueText dialogueAudioLocation:(NSString *)dialogueAudioLocation;

@end
```

Should I be using Property List instead of XML or XML should be fine? I would need easy and quick access to dialogues by passing Page ID & Dialogue ID. In order to achieve this, should I be storing Dialogue model objects inside NSDictionary or should go for other better ways. I would appreciate your suggestions on the approach I should be taking.

Comment: I personally would go for Property List. Dealing with all the xml stuff on your own is pretty pane full compared to plists. And 250kb should be no problem at all.

Comment: Thanks. Does Property list support this kind of complex structure and attributes? for example: <Dlg Id="C1D1" P="L" X="" Y="" W="" H="">. How can I access dialogues by passing Page ID & Dialogue ID if I go with Property List approach?

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem with 250k. IMO you would go better with XML parsing, and making model objects according with your XML tree. This way you can easily manage Objective-C objects. As performance I think is the same, because PLists are XMLs underneath.

Comment: Should I be storing NSDictionary inside NSDictionary or NSArray inside NSDictionary? I would need easy and quick access to dialogues by passing Page ID & Dialogue ID. Some pseudo code would be greatly appreciated.